# My untreated wood got rained on can i still continue my project as usual

Tags: woodworking, advice

So iv been building a couch and doing this outside and my untreated wood got wet.. can I continue  my project as usual or so I need to let it dry before I go sawing it  and drill screws in it? Will it split? Please help I'm new at this woodworking and need help/answers/advice etc

Comment: How long was it wet?   I would think if it's only a few minutes, you could dry it off and go.

Comment: Well it was in a heavy downpour of  rain
 for about an hour
 This morning

Comment: Will depend on how wet it is.  Light rain for a couple of hours or flooding where the wood could soak in water.  Just surface wetness should be okay, but I like my wood dry when working on it, less messy.

Comment: Yes I'd PREFER it to be dry just because but I don't. Wanna postpone my project I'm ready to do this! 

Comment: You should be fine. Once wood is dried it doesn't absorb much water along the length of the lumber, maybe some more at the ends.       If you want to be super safe, take it inside and stack it using stickers   to allow airflow for a week or so.

Comment: See also the woodworking stack; they tend to be pickier about wood condition than folks doing construction are.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest risk is warpage. If it wasn’t thoroughly soaked, it might be salvageable. Don’t worry about splitting. Dry wood actually is more apt to split.